# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: magento2, php-7.2

I have this code:

```
public function getCounter()
    {
        /** @var \Amasty\ShopbyPage\Model\Page $model */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::PAGE);
        return count($model->getConditions());
    }
```

But in line:

```
return count($model->getConditions());
```

I get error in php 7.2:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable

Magento 2.3 version. PHP7.2

In php 7.1 works fine.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked....Please make it answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `count` and `return` direct `$model->getConditions()` add `print_r` and check what result you are getting. You will know what you have to do after that

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to update

```
return count($model->getConditions());
```

to

```
return count($model->getConditions()??[]);
```

as you can't be sure that $model->getConditions() will always be empty.
The reason why it's happening, in php7.2 count on null throws warning, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php "Warn when counting non-countable types" section